# Flutter content intermittently getting clipped on modal_bottom_sheet

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've got [this exact issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54575824/3935156) with a modal_bottom_sheet (without a ListView). I use this exact template on every page in my app with zero issues. This stuff works when not on modal_bottom_sheet. Then I use it on a modal_bottom_sheet and my content gets clipped. The height at which my content gets clipped varies every time I open the modal_bottom_sheet, and many times it doesn't get clipped at all. I've gone over my widgets in Dart Devtools and I don't see any widget taking up this space.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:keyboard_avoider/keyboard_avoider.dart';
import 'package:reactive_forms/reactive_forms.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/common/constants/padding.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/widgets/interactive_non_form_widgets/buttons/elevated_buttons/async_submit_button/async_submit_button_widget.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/widgets/page_layout_helpers/headers/text_header_widget.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/widgets/page_layout_helpers/scaffolds/form_theme_two_page_scaffold_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'child_vegan_item_views/vegan_item_image_form_vm.dart';

class ManageVeganItemImagesPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ManageVeganItemImagesPage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final vm = watch(itemImageFormVmProvider!);
    vm.context = context;
    return ReactiveForm(
        formGroup: vm.form!,
        child: VpFormThemeTwoPageScaffold(
            paddingTop: PAD_1,
            paddingLeft: PAD_0,
            paddingRight: PAD_0,
            paddingBottom: PAD_0,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              VpTextHeader(
                headingChildren: vm.headingChildren(context),
                iconData: FontAwesomeIcons.solidTimes,
                iconSize: 30,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: KeyboardAvoider(
                                autoScroll: true,
                                child: Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: Column(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: vm.formWidgets)))),
                        Container(
                            height: 100,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                PAD_0, PAD_2, PAD_0, PAD_3),
                            child: Center(
                                child: VpAsyncSubmitButton(
                              text: vm.buttonText,
                              onPressed: vm.submit,
                            ))),
                      ])),
            ]));
  }
}
```

`vm.formWidgets` returns any widgets, text fields etc. and has the exact same result. Anyone see what is going wrong?

EDIT: when doing `Navigator.pop(context!);` you see all of the content which was hidden before the view disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in my scenario `modal_bottom_sheet` didn't work well with `keyboard_avoider`. I was just using `keyboard_avoider` to have scrollable forms, but I have just discovered `CustomScrollView` with `SliverList` for the same result without a package.

I changed this:

```
Expanded(
    flex: 1,
    child: KeyboardAvoider(
        autoScroll: true,
        child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment:
                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment:
                    MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: vm.formWidgets))),
```

to this:

```
Expanded(
    flex: 1,
    child: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed(
            vm.formWidgets),
      )
    ])),
```

And then it worked.